# add specific data after checking on startup - spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, h2

I have a `DatabaseLoader` class in my spring application, here is what it looks like :

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class DatabaseLoader {
    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner initDatabase(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
            try{
                userRepository.getOne(100L);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                log.error(e.getMessage());
                userRepository.save(new User());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I was just trying to check every time this application runs, if an user with a specific (100) is present on the database or not, if not log and create one, else just pass.

But this doesn't seem to work, as my request to GET `/user` is empty.

I changed the code a little to check if this piece of code runs or not :

```
log.info("this works");
log.info(userRepository.getOne(100L).toString());
```

And here is what I got :

```
2019-11-02 11:40:58.837  INFO 14332 --- [  restartedMain] com.mua.scraper.DatabaseLoader           : this works
2019-11-02 11:40:58.872 ERROR 14332 --- [  restartedMain] com.mua.scraper.DatabaseLoader           : could not initialize proxy [com.mua.scraper.model.User#100] - no Session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@Configuration` to `@Component`

Use this for command-line runner

```
@Component
public class CommandLineDatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        try{
            userRepository.getOne(100L);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization